# Zookeeper started but gives no response

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I've started zookeeper with zkServer.sh

```
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/hduser/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

But when I use

```
echo ruok | nc 172.20.30.102 2181
```

It shows nothing but command prompt

zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/home/hduser/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
```

java on my sytem

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.10.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

can anyone tell me whats going wrong here?

EDIT:

zkServer.sh status gives

```
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/hduser/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: standalone
```

zooeeper.out

```
2014-02-21 23:45:59,995 [myid:] - INFO  [Thread-1:NIOServerCnxn@1001] - Closed socket connection for client /172.20.30.102:38820 (no session established for client)
2014-02-24 16:31:39,786 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /172.20.30.102:50204
2014-02-24 16:31:39,790 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@821] - Processing ruok command from /172.20.30.102:50204
2014-02-24 16:31:39,793 [myid:] - INFO  [Thread-2:NIOServerCnxn@1001] - Closed socket connection for client /172.20.30.102:50204 (no session established for client)
2014-02-24 16:32:40,887 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:34517
2014-02-24 16:32:40,888 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@821] - Processing srvr command from /127.0.0.1:34517
2014-02-24 16:32:40,913 [myid:] - INFO  [Thread-3:NIOServerCnxn@1001] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:34517 (no session established for client)
2014-02-24 16:59:15,506 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /172.20.30.102:40481
2014-02-24 16:59:15,521 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@821] - Processing ruok command from /172.20.30.102:40481
2014-02-24 16:59:15,528 [myid:] - INFO  [Thread-4:NIOServerCnxn@1001] - Closed socket connection for client /172.20.30.102:40481 (no session established for client)
2014-02-24 17:00:40,720 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:57204
2014-02-24 17:00:40,725 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@821] - Processing srvr command from /127.0.0.1:57204
2014-02-24 17:00:40,730 [myid:] - INFO  [Thread-5:NIOServerCnxn@1001] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:57204 (no session established for client)
2014-02-24 17:06:57,568 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:45276
2014-02-24 17:06:57,577 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@821] - Processing srvr command from /127.0.0.1:45276
  2014-02-24 17:06:57,584 [myid:] - INFO  [Thread-6:NIOServerCnxn@1001] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:45276 (no session established for client)
```

Comment: what is the response from `sh zkServer.sh status`?

Comment: Maybe this is obvious but have you tailed the zookeeper.out file?

Comment: what does the zookeeper log say?

Comment: @Muhammad Yasir, posted the result of status command

Comment: @Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz. posted the log

Comment: Can you try `echo ruok | nc localhost 2181`. The server has started. You can also check with `netstat -tlnp | grep 2181`